# RMI - stub creation with rmic

Tags: java, rmi

I am stuck with creating stubs for my simple RMI implementation. With command line, I am at directory, where I have my class files stored.

For me it is: C:\Users\John\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testServer\build\classes\RMI

RMI here is the package I have my files in. Now when I am in this folder, I tri to make stubs with rmic -v1.2 -keep CountingOnServer, but command line writes me, that class CountingOnServer not found. No matter what I am doing, still it is writing such a unbelivable mistake... do you know how to solve that?

Thx

Comment: Since java 1.4, the skel classes creation is no longer requiered, and so is it for stubs since 1.5.

Are you sure you need rmic?

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6.0_18 so it is really not necessare to have stubs?

Comment: @Alf Skeletons became unnecessary in **1.2.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a guess, issue is that `CountingOnServer` is inside some package, so you should use full name like `RMI.CountingOnServer`. Don't forget to run rmic from the the class-path root which in your case seems to be `build\classes` directory.

Comment: Still if I run it from build/classes as a RMI.CountingOnServer, I have the same error - class RMI.CountingOnServer not found.

Comment: What is the package of `CountingOnServer`?

Comment: solved - I had to remove packages and then stubs were generated normally.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your RMI implementation in packages run rmic at the root of your class files,
ex,

```
|-- build
|   |-- classes
|   |   `-- com
|   |       |-- client
|   |       |   `-- TestRMI.class
|   |       |-- rmi
|   |       |   |-- Hello.class
|   |       |   |-- HelloInterface.class
|   |       |   `-- Hello_Stub.class
|   |       `-- RMTServer
|   |           `-- RmiServer.class
```

I have my classes in build/classes/com/rmi directory so, to create stubs I can run rmic at the root as,

../build/classes/rmic com.rmi.Hello